# Login on same page, check SESSION without reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I currently have a form at the top of every page on my website that lets the user input the username and password to login.

but Once the button is clicked, I use JQuery AJAX method to submit it to login.php without page refresh where it validates credentials and returns users whether the username / password submitted was valid or invalid.

Finally, the result is returned back to the page the user tried to login on.

I would also like the page to after once there is a successful login, the form disappears and is replaced with "Welcome back, USER!"

Everything works except for I want this to happen without a page reload. Here is what I have so far:-

Display form if session is not set, otherwise say Welcome back, user:-

```
<div class="user">
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
        $logged_user = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
        print("<p>Welcome back, $logged_user!</p>");
    }
    else {
        print('<div class="forms">
            <form id="login">
                <label>Username <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></label>
                <label>Password <input type="text" name="password" id="password"></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login" id="login">
                <span class="error"></span>
            </form>
        </div>');
    }
?>
</div>
```

**Javascript / AJAX to handle submission:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
        if(username != '' && password != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(responseText) {
                if(responseText == 0) {
                    $("error").html("Invalid login.");
                }
                else if(responseText == 1) {
                    window.location = 'index.php';
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

And my login.php does everything fine.

Right now, the only way for my page to update to show the Welcome back message is if I include the line: `window.location = 'index.php';` so that the page reloads. But without this, the user will have logged in successfully but will not be able to see this.

Is there a way to do this without AngularJS? This is for a class and we are not allowed to use frameworks, which has been quite frustrating! Thanks!

Comment: You can show/hide div on the basis of successful/invalid login..have you tried it ??

Comment: Where is the problem? You obviously already know how to update the contents of an HTML element (because you are doing that with the error message – well, almost, since you want to select `.error`, not `error`) – so what is stopping you from applying that very same logic to a different element …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code,

```
<div class="user">
<div class="after_login" style="display:none">
<?php

        $logged_user = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
        print("<p>Welcome back, $logged_user!</p>");?>
</div>
<div class = "before_login">

        print('<div class="forms">
            <form id="login">
                <label>Username <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></label>
                <label>Password <input type="text" name="password" id="password"></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login" id="login">
                <span class="error"></span>
            </form>
        </div>');
?>
</div>
</div>
```

in script use like this instead of:

```
 window.location = 'index.php';
```

use below lines,

```
  $('.after_login').show();
  $('.before_login').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic HTML (DHTML).

The success function you don't redirect instead using jquery to change the content.

Something like this:

```
success: function(responseText) {
    if(responseText == 0) {
        alert('Invalid login');
    }
    else if(responseText == 1) {
        // Success
        $('#login').parent().append('<p>Welcome back, '+username+'!</p>');
        $('#login').remove();

    }
    else {
        alert('Another Invalid login');
    }
}
```

The API Login return:

- 0  if invalid
- 1 if valid

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
        $logged_user = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
//Leave out the print(Welcome...) part, it won't do anything because the page won't be refreshed.    
}
else{
exit('1');
}
```

In the Ajax, don't worry about responseText == 0, just stick with ==1:

```
success: function(responseText) { 
if(responseText == "1") {
alert("Nope");
}
else {
$("#successdiv").html("welcome...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some modification in your javascript code as below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
        if(username != '' && password != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(responseText) {
                if(responseText.status == 'invalid') {
                    $(".error").html("Invalid login.");
                }
                else if(responseText.status == 'valid') {
                    $('.after_login').html('Welcome back,'+responseText.username);
                    $('.after_login').show();
                    $('.before_login').hide();
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

In above example, I have added one extra line dataType: "json", So now you have need to send output in json format from your login.php and also some modification done in success.

```html
$response = array();

// $result variable get result from your database
if(count($result) == 0)
{
    $response['status'] = 'invalid';
}else{

    $response['status'] = 'valid';
    $response['username'] = $result['username'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

So your success become like that below

```js
success: function(responseText) {
  if(responseText.status == 'invalid') {
    $(".error").html("Invalid login.");
  }
  else if(responseText.status == 'valid') {
    $('.after_login').html('Welcome back,'+responseText.username);
    $('.after_login').show();
    $('.before_login').hide();
  }
  else {
    alert('Error');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *login.php*, change success condition to output username instead of 1. So *responseText* will have the username on ajax callback.

Remove the final else condition in your ajax success, and do something like this in the success condition

```
$('.forms').html('<p>Welcome back, ' + responseText + '!</p>');
```